# Gently move prefabs to open space before instantiating a new one

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

i'm trying to instantiate several prefabs in front of the camera using this code:

```
public GameObject prefab;
private uint instantiatedPrefabs = 0;

public void createObj()
{
    if(instantiatedPrefabs < 10)
    {
        Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(1, prefab.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.size.y/2, 1), Quaternion.identity);
        instantiatedPrefabs++;
    }
}
```

It works flawlessly, but if a new prefab appears inside one or several preexisting prefabs, then the preexisting prefabs experience something like an explosion and get flown away of the new one.

How can i detect there are prefabs in the position where i want to put the new prefab and gently move them  to the sideways to open enough space?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to have a patter in mind like a grid or something. So you know you're going to spawn 10 game objects so just place them at like new Vector3(1 , instantiatedPrefabs , 1) so they'll just be in a vertical line. You can have a variable for x position.

Comment: The problem is that the user can move around the recently spawned objects :(